# How to send data from 2 different page to a php via an ajax call together?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I need the user to fill a form and then I want to pass that data to another page like so

**Site1**

```
<form action="site2.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Site2 will read the name and email from site1 and include it inside a ajax call

**Site2 Javascript**

```
function addMarker(location, map) {
        // Add the marker at the clicked location
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,          
          map: map
        });

        $.ajax({
          url: 'insertToDatabase.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { lat: location.lat(),
                  long : location.lng(),
                  name : $_POST['name'], // something like this
                  email: $_POST['email'] // something like this
                }
        });
      }
```

Is there a way to do something like this for the Ajax call?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. in site2, just capture the POST vars, then ask PHP to print their values wherever you need it

**site2.php**

```
<?php
//capture the POST vars
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
?>
...HTML & JS code GOES HERE....
```

Then later on down the page, where your ajax function is, you can re-enter PHP mode to output the values:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'insertToDatabase.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { lat: location.lat(),
    long : location.lng(),
    name : '<?= $name ?>',
    email: '<?= $email ?>'
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that ASAP :)
However, meanwhile another interesting idea came up. Is it possible to trigger a pop up form in the addMarker() function and pass the submitted form data from the pop up straight to the ajax?

This way, I don't even need `site1.php`

Comment: Yep; you can use `prompt()` function to ask the user for input, capture the results and include it in your `data` parameter.  Check it out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: Yes, I was looking at `prompt()`. However, it unfortunately can only provide one input. I need at least 2 inputs :(

Comment: Then you'll need to figure out how to code a modal form with Javascript, or use `prompt()` twice, capturing the inputs one at a time.  By the way, I added quote marks around `<?= $name ?>` and `<?= $email ?>` in my answer. It won't work without them.